# my kivy program is printing the name of last button irrespective of whichever button i press

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, logic

i want to create a kivy program which prints the name of the button which is clicked by me..but irrespective of whichever button i press it always prints the name of the last button. My code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

class AllAccsPage(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AllAccsPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.back_butt = Button(text='Back', pos_hint={'x':0.05, 'y':0.08}, size_hint=(0.2,0.1))
        self.back_butt.bind(on_release=self.back)
        self.add_widget(self.back_butt)
        usernames = self.grab_accounts()
        self.butt_height = 0.8
        all_butts = {}
        for ind in range(len(usernames)):
            all_butts[f'butt{ind}'] = Button(text=usernames[ind], size_hint = (0.2, 0.1),
            pos_hint = {'x':0.1, 'y':self.butt_height}, background_color=(0,0,0,1))
            all_butts[f'butt{ind}'].bind(on_release= self.open_acc)
            self.add_widget(all_butts[f'butt{ind}'])
            self.butt_height -= 0.1
        for x in all_butts.keys():
            def save_info(self):
                print(all_butts[x].text)
            all_butts[x].bind(on_press=save_info)
    def grab_accounts(self):
        my_f = open('usernames and passwords.txt', 'r')
        text = my_f.readlines()
        plain_text = [re.sub('\n','', line) for line in text]
        all_dict = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in plain_text]
        all_usernames = [each['username'] for each in all_dict]
        return all_usernames

class DiaryApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AllAccsPage
if name=='main'
    DiaryApp.run()
```

How can I correct my logic so that the name that button which i press will be printed

Comment: See https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Comment: sir i read the entire page but i m not able to understand how that is related to my question. plz explain what exactly is wrong

Comment: It's related to your question in that it describes what you have done wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Note that your `def save_info` is the function that hits the issue, try declaring it as something like `def safe_info(self, x=x)`